# Rounding to Specific Number in Excel Based on Value Range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for an excel formula that will round numbers based on their individual values to a specific amount. For example:

```
Numbers between:
.01 and .19 - rounded to .19
.20 and .29 - rounded to .29
.30 and .49 - rounded to .49
.50 and .79 - rounded to .79
.80 and .99 - rounded to .99
1.00 and 1.19 - rounded to 1.19
1.20 and 1.29 - rounded to 1.29
1.39 and 1.49 - rounded to 1.49
1.50 and 1.79 - rounded to 1.79
1.80 and 1.99 - rounded to 1.99
2.00 and 2.49 - rounded to 2.49
2.50 and 2.99 - rounded to 2.99
```

I need to do this for a group of numbers that range from .01 to 100 and at various intervals throughout that range, which I tried to illustrate above, the number that I am rounding to needs to change.

Hope this makes sense. I appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Since the spacing is not the same you will need a lookup table and use VLOOKUP

Comment: What have you tried?  The standard rounding function would seem to be what you want, since you want to round up with a 0.5+ value, and round down when it's below 0.5.  Knowing what you have tried would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Create a lookup table with the lower threshold and desired output:

[image]

Then use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,F:G,2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the spacing is uniformly 0.2, then the following formula does the job:

```
    =MROUND(D4+0.1,0.2)-0.01
```

However, from your sample, it seems the spacing is not uniform. So you'll have to create a lookup table with the lower bounds, like this:

```
 0.01   0.19
 0.20   0.29
 0.30   0.49
 0.50   0.79
 0.80   0.99
 1.00   1.19
 1.20   1.29
 1.39   1.49
 1.50   1.79
 1.80   1.99
 2.00   2.49
 2.50   2.99
```

You can then use the following formula:

```
    =INDEX($J$5:$J$16,MATCH(D3,$I$5:$I$16,1))
```

Where J5:J16 have the values you need, I5:I16 have the lower bounds, and D3 has the value which you need to round.

I prefer INDEX-MATCH to VLOOKUP because it is more clear on what it does and hence, more reliable.